# HttpClient c# - A task was canceled at SendASync

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, httpclient

I am getting `TaskCanceledException` even though I increase timeout. It surprisingly it not even occurring always, exception is only occurring sometime and I am unable to find pattern to reproduce error. I added the Exception Trace and Code I am using to make network call.

[image: Exception Trace Image]

```
public static void getResponseFromUrlAsync<T>(T payload, string url,
     Action<string> onSuccess, Action<string> onFailure)
{
    string contentType = "application/json";
    httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    HttpRequestMessage requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage();
    requestMsg.RequestUri = new Uri(NetworkCallUrls.baseUri + url);
    Utils.debugLog("Url", NetworkCallUrls.baseUri + url);

    // try
    //{
    string auth = "Bearer " + Objects.GlobalVars.GetValue<string>("access_token"); // //"x1VwaR1otS66ZCTlgtv3X9aaSNpDOn"; //
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);
    requestMsg.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

    requestMsg.Content = new StringContent(
                   Utils.stringifyData(payload),
                   Encoding.UTF8,
                   contentType);

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header

    makeNetworkCallCheckResponseStatusAndExecuteCorrospondingAction(requestMsg, onSuccess, onFailure, progressBarStatus);
}

internal static void disposeConnection(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    httpClient.Dispose();
    httpClient = null;
}

private static async void makeNetworkCallCheckResponseStatusAndExecuteCorrospondingAction(
    HttpRequestMessage requestMsg, Action<string> onSuccess,
    Action<string> onFailure, Action<bool> progressBarStatus)
{
    Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 1");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMsg);
    Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 2");
    ResponseStatus responseStatus = checkResponseStatusAndExecuteActionAccordinglyAsync(response);
    Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 3");
    if (responseStatus.isSuccess)
    {
        Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 4");
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 5");
        onSuccess(responseString);
        Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 6");
    }
    else
    {
        Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 7");
        onFailure(responseStatus.failureResponse);
        Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 8");
    }
    Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 9");
    disposeConnection(httpClient);
    Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 10");
}
```

I am using the above code to make API call , I am getting TaskCanceledException in `HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMsg);` line.

could some one help me in resolving this.I searched in internet and increase timeout as well but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should await both the `makeNetworkCallCheckResponseStatusAndExecuteCorrospondingAction` method and the `getResponseFromUrlAsync` method. This means that you need to change the return type from `void` to `Task`:

```
public static async Task getResponseFromUrlAsync<T>(T payload, string url, Action<string> onSuccess, Action<string> onFailure)
{
    string contentType = "application/json";
    httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    HttpRequestMessage requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage();
    requestMsg.RequestUri = new Uri(NetworkCallUrls.baseUri + url);
    Utils.debugLog("Url", NetworkCallUrls.baseUri + url);


    string auth = "Bearer " + Objects.GlobalVars.GetValue<string>("access_token"); // //"x1VwaR1otS66ZCTlgtv3X9aaSNpDOn"; //
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);
    requestMsg.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

    requestMsg.Content = new StringContent(
                   Utils.stringifyData(payload),
                   Encoding.UTF8,
                   contentType);

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header

    await makeNetworkCallCheckResponseStatusAndExecuteCorrospondingAction(requestMsg, onSuccess, onFailure, progressBarStatus)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}

internal static void disposeConnection(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    httpClient.Dispose();
    httpClient = null;
}

private static async Task makeNetworkCallCheckResponseStatusAndExecuteCorrospondingAction(
    HttpRequestMessage requestMsg, Action<string> onSuccess,
    Action<string> onFailure, Action<bool> progressBarStatus)
{
    Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 1");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMsg).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 2");
    ResponseStatus responseStatus = checkResponseStatusAndExecuteActionAccordinglyAsync(response);
    Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 3");
    if (responseStatus.isSuccess)
    {
        Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 4");
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 5");
        onSuccess(responseString);
        Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 6");
    }
    else
    {
        Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 7");
        onFailure(responseStatus.failureResponse);
        Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 8");
    }
    Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 9");
    disposeConnection(httpClient);
    Utils.debugLog("IN MAKE NETWORK CALL 10");
}
```

...and `await` the method when you call it:

```
await getResponseFromUrlAsync<..>(...);
```

Comment: I think for me the problem is httpClient is updated with new one before the api call_1 is finished because I am making multiple calls one after other with out any delay , so before the previous call is returned I am making another call

Comment: But yeah I will update the code , as per best practices , thanks :)

Comment: That's why you should await the methods.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments which I hope will help you resolve your problem:

1. `async` methods should return `Task` if you have nothing to return, not `void`. You don't have to actually return a `Task` object, the compiler will handle this. The only exception are WinForms and WebForms event handlers.
2. Your `getResponseFromUrlAsync` method is not async, but it should be. You should add an `async` modifier, and return `Task`. Then, `await makeNetworkCallCheckResponseStatusAndExecuteCorrospondingAction(...)`. This could be the source of your problem - you are not awaiting your async operation to complete before returning.
3. On a general note, it seems like your `httpClient` variable is defined globally somewhere. You can easily run into a NullReferenceException, because `makeNetworkCallCheckResponseStatusAndExecuteCorrospondingAction` can be called even without calling `getResponseFromUrlAsync` first, and so can `disposeConnection`. If your class always uses the `httpClient`, initialize it in the constructor or declaration. If it isn't, check that it's not null at the start of the method.

Comment: For 2nd , I am waiting in 'makeNetworkCallCheckResponseStatusAndExecuteCorrospondingAction' so I thought I don't need await and async and task as return in 'getResponseFromUrlAsync'

Comment: @djkp, you do. `makeNetworkCallCheckResponseStatusAndExecuteCorrospondingAction` is async, and if you don't await it, you return before it finishes execution. Once you start with async, it's async all the way to program root.