# TaskCanceledException in Google Drive APIs

Tags: vb.net, exception, upload, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

it has been some days since I implemented in several PCs my Google Drive upload programme. It is developed in VB.NET console app and I can say it works out pretty good. Except that in some PCs it continues throwing the taskcanceled exception. Basically the programme works at night, where the internet traffic in the pcs should be likely to 0 and it continues trying to upload to a google folder until it succesfully do it OR the time (of an hour usually) runs out.
The Exception looks like this

```
Ex: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occured. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
   in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   in System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   in System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   in Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload.Upload() in C:\Apiary\2021-09-08.15-52-39\Src\Support\Google.Apis\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:riga 388
   in TeraDriveServ.Service1.UploadFile(String FilePath) in C:\Sviluppo\TeraDriveServ\Service1.vb:row 291
---> (Internal exception 0) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A Task was canceled.<---
```

This is the code I use

```
Private Sub UploadFile(FilePath As String)
    Dim pathDb As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DB")
    If Service.ApplicationName <> "Google Drive VB Dot Net" Then CreateService()
    Dim mail As String = ""
    Dim destinatari As String = ""
    Dim TheFile As New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
    Dim nome As String = Path.GetFileName(FilePath)
    Dim infofile As New IO.FileInfo(FilePath)
    ' I get some data from the file
    Dim dataultimaModifica As DateTime = infofile.LastWriteTime
    Dim nomefileeffettivo As String = infofile.Name
    Dim estensione = Path.GetExtension(FilePath)
    'Getting the file folder
    Dim folderId As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CARTELLADRIVE")
    TheFile.Parents = New List(Of ParentReference) From {New ParentReference() With {.Id = folderId}}
    TheFile.Title = nome
    TheFile.Description = ""
    Dim esiste As Boolean = False
    ' A query to check if the file is uploaded
    Using con As System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection = New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=" & pathDb & "databaseFile.db3")

        Using com As System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand = New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(con)
            con.Open()
            com.CommandText = "Select ID FROM CARICATI WHERE NOME = '" & nome & "' AND DATA='" & dataultimaModifica & "'"

            Using reader As System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()

                While reader.Read()
                    esiste = True

                End While

                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    If esiste = True Then
        ' already loaded
        Return
    Else
        Select Case estensione
            Case ".bak"
                TheFile.MimeType = "application/octet-stream"
            Case ".zip"
                TheFile.MimeType = "application/zip"
                'Case ".jpeg", ".jpg"
                '    TheFile.MimeType = "image/ jpeg"
                'Case ".txt"
                '    TheFile.MimeType = "text/plain"
                'Case ".pdf"
                '    TheFile.MimeType = "application/pdf"
                'Case ".xls"
                '    TheFile.MimeType = "application/ vnd.ms - excel"
                'Case ".doc"
                '    TheFile.MimeType = "application/msword"
                'Case ".docx"
                '    TheFile.MimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
                'Case ".xlsx"
                '    TheFile.MimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                'Case ".odt"
                '    TheFile.MimeType = "application/ vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"
            Case Else
          ' I dont like the file extension
                Return
        End Select

        Dim fatto As Integer = 0
        ' I upload the file details in the DB
        Using con As System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection = New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=" & pathDb & "databaseFile.db3")

            Using com As System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand = New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(con)
                con.Open()
                com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CARICATI (NOME,DATA) VALUES('" & nome & "','" & dataultimaModifica & "') "
                com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                fatto = con.LastInsertRowId
               ' UPLOADED
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End If


    Try
        Dim ByteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
        Dim Stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ByteArray)
        Dim UploadRequest As Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = Service.Files.Insert(TheFile, Stream, TheFile.MimeType)
        logger.Debug("Oggetto creato")
        ' UploadRequest.ContentStream.WriteTimeout = 600000

        'If contaUp = 0 Then
        '    UploadRequest.Service.HttpClient.Timeout = Service.HttpClient.Timeout
        'End If
        'contaUp = 1
        logger.Debug("Starting upload: " & DateTime.Now)
        ' Here is where the exception points at, the Google Upload() Method
        UploadRequest.Upload()
        logger.Debug("Upload completed: " & DateTime.Now)
        Dim file As File = Nothing
        file = UploadRequest.ResponseBody
        If file Is Nothing Then
            logger.Debug("Upload failed")
            ' deletes the data from db to try again
            AnnulloCaricamento(nome, dataultimaModifica, pathDb) 

        Else
        
        
        ' I send some stuff to a server
            logger.Debug("Cerco di fare POST")
            Dim testoSucc As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TESTOS")
            POST(nomefileeffettivo, dataultimaModifica)
            eseguito = True
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' deletes the data from db to try again
        AnnulloCaricamento(nome, dataultimaModifica, pathDb) ''05/10/2021
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClient c# - A task was canceled at SendASync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682717/httpclient-c-sharp-a-task-was-canceled-at-sendasync)

Comment: Unluckily it doesnt, the Upload() is actually a ResumableUpload and the comment of the method says "Uploads the content to the server. This method is synchronous and will block  until the upload is completed."
I guess that somehow my code gets stopped...

Comment: It looks like you aren't disposing `Stream` - you should put it in a `using` statement.

Comment: I m not that pratical, could you give me an example??

Comment: For an example, on how to use a `using` statement, see the code that you posted.

Comment: I tried much stuff since last time, but I still struggle to find a good solution.. It seems more like a VB.NET timeout than a GDrive error: I set the method to Asynch to use the asynch upload method on these pcs where the program doesnt work but nothing actuallly changed.